# Image on local disk is not loading in Tomcat project configuration

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, canvas

I am working on a project using HTML5 and JavaScript. I am loading an image from the C: drive like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
    };
    imageObj.src = "file:///C:/Images/Demo.jpg";
  };
```

The image is loading perfectly on this page. When try the same thing in my project, the image won't load in a canvas element. I am getting the following error from the browser:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)[nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Project its not advisable to use direct path you should use a related path as per your server directory
as  '<%=request.getContextPath()%>'/Remaing_path_from_webContent_folder_of_project

Hope it will work

Comment: Thanks for reply K.P. It means i have to relative path rather than directory path. Actually i am using an input type "file" in my div, from where user will get a FileChooser, then after selecting file, how will i get the relative path of file.

Comment: Ideally what you should do what ever file user upload or select you need to read  that file and write same file on your sever to some specific directory .this can be  done using java IO ........ Now you just need to read that file from your directory available on server not from any user disk. If find any problem please share

Comment: if i follow this way.then is it refer to 'ZER0 FOOTPRINT'. Because my project has restrictions to done all the work with 'ZERO FOOTPRINT'

Comment: Sorry Sir No idea about ZERO FOOTPRINT

Comment: K.P. is there any other way to do this. without coping file on server. So that i could use that choosen file